# Chinese tattoo help

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I want a tattoo saying 時間 (time). However I was told this is not suitable for a tattoo. I wanted to know how to say time in chinese with a deep meaning. Is there a way to add a character so that it would not look funny?

Comment: This smells offtopic. We don't provide advice for tattoos here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which aspect of 'time' you are thinking about? What a similar word/phrase would be in English?

Comment: I voted to close - It's off topic. This is a question about culture. Furthermore it's subjective. Oh and if you want my advice - Don't get *any* tattoo!

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is not the answer you are looking for, but here it is anyway...

[image]

Comment: My favorite was when I saw a girl with 火 tattooed on herself - I didn't have the heart to explain to her that it's pronounced "Whore"

Comment: I think it's only a matter of time. Chinese really like English and like to be appear able to understand it. I saw tissue paper yesterday marked "Smooth and Tenacious"

Comment: Smooth and tenacious actually sounds like really good qualities for a tissue...

Comment: @juckele I'd buy it :D

Comment: Ha, I've seen this before.

Comment: @trideceth12 that's funny, but that 're' part goes only for Northern Chinese Mandarin speakers.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, 時間 would be awkward... that's literally the noun "time", like "do you have any time?".

That seems awkward in English too to get such a tattoo.

Maybe you'd prefer something more poetic? Like...

> 永恆 yong3 heng2 = eternity

Or maybe even get an idiom... those are usually pretty:

> 萬古千秋 wan4 gu3 qian1 qiu = For all eternity

Comment: I don't think it's awkward at all. The question is way too subjective.

Answer (score 0):

亙古不變 - never changed from ancient time

恆久 - for a long time